# Concatenate strings to form a variable name

Tags: python

I have a number of variables in my python script containing integers e.g.,

```
lab19 = 100-50 #50
lab20 = 200-20 #180
```

I have a while loop that loops through an incrementing counter calling a function each time. The function needs to pass the variable, but the 19 and 20 parts of the variable name come from the counter.

I have tried this,

```
y = 1
while y < 21:
  bundleRun('lab' + str(y))
  y += 1
```

but that is passing the literal string 'lab1' value to the function.

How do I get my code to pass the variable value (e.g., 50) to my function based on the counter?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the `globals` and `locals` [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), although may be a good idea to turn separate variables into a collection. Also consider to use `for y in range(1, 21)` as a simpler alternative to `while`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store your data in a list or dict so it can be accessed by index or by key. But if you really need to access a local variable by name you can use `locals()`

```
y = 1
while y < 21:
  a = locals()['lab' + str(y)]  # value stored in variable a
  y += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you *can* do this, you *shouldn't*.[^1]  Dynamically created variables in python are a code smell (unlike e.g. TeX, where this kind of thing is routine).

Instead, store everything in a collection:

```py
results = {"lab19": 50, "lab20": 180}
for lab, result in results.keys():
    bundleRun(result)
```

Note that your `while` loop could be better written as:

```py
for y in range(1,21):
    ...
```

If you really do need to do this, the other answer with `locals()` is the way to go.

[^1] but it could be worse: you're only trying to access them.  Perhaps you *have* to do this---but if you have control over the variables the pythonic way is to use a collection.